# How to split Container.DataItem string in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `List<string>` which returns strings of this format `yyyy-MM-dd;Price`. This list is bound to my listview and I'd like to split my string into the two fields of the listview: the first field would contain yyyy-MM-dd and the second one would contain the price.

Here's what I tried

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCodeUsager" 
           runat="server" 
           Text='<%#  Container.DataItem.ToString().Split(';')[0] %>' />
```

Unfortunately, I get an error saying the server tag is not correct.

I know I could pass a list of object, but I was wondering if there was a solution with a list of string?

Comment: try `\'` instead of just `'`. or create a list of a class instead that preprocesses the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCodeUsager" 
       runat="server" 
       Text="<%#  Container.DataItem.ToString().Split(';')[0] %>" />
```

You need to swap the ' for the text attribute to " since if you don't it will interfere with the split.